# How to pass currency as argument?

Tags: icu, react-intl

I've got my custom formats

```
{
  number: {
    USD: {
       style: 'currency',
       currency: 'USD',
    },
    EUR: {
       style: 'currency',
       currency: 'EUR',
    },
  },
}
```

and I want to create an ICU message so that I could pass `currency` as a parameter:

```
formatMessage(message, {amount: 40, currency: 'EUR'})
```

I would imagine something like this:

```
{amount, number, {currency}}
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Embedding placeholders into the style argument doesn't seem to be supported by the [DecimalFormat](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/text/DecimalFormat.html) specification, so I can only assume not supported by the React implementation either.

ICU [MessageFormat](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/text/MessageFormat.html) has a currency formatter built in which would use the locale data it has available, so for a Eurozone locale, you just need `{amount,number,currency}`.

If your "custom formats" data is available to the formatter, then perhaps that works? I've not tried it as I don't develop in React.